# Populate C output parameter

Tags: c, char

This is a beginner question, but please bear with me. I'd like to pass in a char* to a function, and have it populated, with the contents of multiple existing strings. Here's what I have (and doesn't work)

```
int func(char *out) {
    int i;
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    char array[x][y];

    out = malloc(x * y + x);
    memset(out, 0x00, strlen(out));
    for (i=0; i<x; i++) {
            strcat(out, array[i]);
            strcat(out, "\n");
    }
}

//main
    char *result;
    func(result);
```

Comment: Please show your actual code - this example won't even compile.

Comment: You can't use `strlen(out)`! Read up what `strlen` does (or how C strings work, for that matter). You need to say `x * y + x` instead. And absolutely make sure that every `array[i]` is null-terminated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `char*` is just a pointer, passing it in doesnt let you pass a new one back out again. You need to pass a `char**` like so:

```
void get_name( char** ppname ){
  char * pname = strdup("my name is fred");
  *ppname = pname;
}
```

You then feed the function somewhere to put the pointer like so:

```
char * name;
get_name( &name );
printf( "got '%s'\n", name );
free( name );
```

Comment: That works fine. Why doesn't this work: out = (char*)malloc(1000); strcat((*out), someString);

Comment: @RobertVbr, that probably doesnt work in your original func because you pass in uninitialized memory, strcat may never find a NUL terminator to start appending after.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you never allocated memory for your `result` variable - it's just a pointer that points to nowhere.

```
char result[1000]; // change size as needed if you know the size ahead of time
func(result);
```

or

```
char *pResult = malloc ( 1000 ); // allocate dynamically

if ( pResult != NULL )
    func ( pResult );

...

if ( pResult != NULL )
    free ( pResult );
```

You should also pass in the size of your buffer so your `func` function can check and verify that there's enough space available for its output.

Both of these solutions assume that you allocate your buffer outside of `func`. If you want to allocate the output buffer inside `func` than - as suggested by [Als](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511326/682404) - you need to pass a pointer-to-pointer. In that case, you should also return the size of the buffer so the caller knows how many bytes are available in the buffer.